# How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?

Tags: eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I have in my source code:

```cpp
// foo.cpp
struct foo
{
  foo() {}

  #ifdef I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE
  void bar() {}
  #endif
};
```

In my Makefile I have

```make
foo.o: foo.cpp
        g++ -c -DI_WANT_THIS_FEATURE foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

This compiles fine from the command line as well as with the external builder that I have created in Eclipse (which basically defines a few environment variables and calls `make`) and I can call `foo::bar()`.

However, in the Eclipse CDT source code editor, the part where I define `foo::bar()` has a grey background (suggesting that `foo::bar()` would not be included in the build) and code completion on objects of type `foo` does not suggest `bar()` as a method that can be called.

How can I define the `I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE` macro in an Eclipse CDT makefile project with custom makefile so that it is known to the source code editor and the code completion?

Comment: See also: [Eclipse CDT Does not track macro defines correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270508/eclipse-cdt-does-not-track-macro-defines-correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it: **Project** -> **Properties** -> **C/C++ General** -> **Paths and Symbols**

Choose the **Symbols** tab and **Add...** a new Symbol with **Name** `I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE` and a **Value** of `1`.

Comment: I think question is about automatically parsing the defines from makefile and then use them for indexing and code highlighting for enabled and disabled parts of source code.

Comment: You should also check the boxes for `Add to all configurations` and `Add to all languages`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Oswald's answer:

If you have several build configurations, the default behavior of the Eclipse Indexer seem to be that it always uses the first build configuration.

In my case the define was only defined in the 3rd build configuration, so the solution provided by Oswald did not help.

To change this globally, select **Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer**.
Choose **Use active build configuration**

You could also choose to override the global settings in the project settings under **Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Indexer** and select **Enable project specific settings** followed by selecting **Use active build configuration**.

After this, the solution provided by Oswald should work:

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
>
> Choose the Symbols tab and Add... a new Symbol with Name I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE and a Value of 1.

Comment: It appears that if you check the boxes for `Add to all configurations` and `Add to all languages` while Adding the Symbol in the first place, you won't need to also check `Use active build configuration`, as you specify, because the symbol will be added to all build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Using -D with almost every compiler and just supplying a name like -DI_WANT_THIS_FEATURE defines the symbol I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE with a value of 1.

The eclipse indexer/editor apparently does not know that, so:

```
#if I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE
this code is marked inactive in editor,
but will be seen by compiler and cause error
#endif
```

where:

```
#ifdef I_WANT_THIS_FEATURE
this code is marked active in editor
#endif
```

So, this is really a problem with eclipse not knowing that default value for a symbol defined through -D is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse makes this rather confusing, since there are multiple places to set this, and the settings are coupled, but here's how it works:

Note: if you've followed my instructions below, or the other answers here, and it still won't work, check out my more-extensive troubleshooting section [on my website here](https://gabrielstaples.com/eclipse-defining-custom-macros-for-indexer/#troubleshooting).

### To set custom macros for a given project (affects both building and indexing in Eclipse)

Here's my preferred way to do it.

In this example we will set the following defines *at the Eclipse project level* (for its indexer and builder) rather than in your source code.

```cpp
#define ARDUINO 1000
#define AVR
#define __AVR_ATmega328__
```

If you were defining them at the command-line when manually building a `gcc` or `g++` project, the above `#define`s would look like this (search for `-Dmacro` in the [`man gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) pages for details):

```bash
-DARDUINO=1000 -DAVR -D__AVR_ATmega328__
```

So, do the following in your Eclipse project. My project here is called "Arduino 1.8.13" (see full screenshot of this a couple images below):

**Right-click on your project** in the "Project Explorer" pane on the left --> **Properties** --> **C/C++ General** --> **Paths and Symbols** --> **Symbols** tab --> select either **GNU C** or **GNU C++** --> click the **Add** button at the top-right --> type `ARDUINO` for **name** and `1000` for **value** --> BE SURE TO CHECK THE 2 BOXES FOR **Add to all configurations** and **Add to all languages** (unless you don't want those behaviors) --> click **OK**.
[image]

Repeat this step for all defines, as follows. Be sure to check the boxes for **Add to all configurations** and **Add to all languages** (unless you don't want those behaviors) for each one:

1. Name: `ARDUINO`, Value: `1000`
2. Name: `AVR`, Value: (leave empty)
3. Name: `__AVR_ATmega328__`, Value: (leave empty)

Here's a screenshot showing the first one. Notice all the highlighted sections to click or pay attention to:

[image]

Once you've done this for all macros you wish to define (ex: the 3 above), you will see the following:

1. If you checked the box for **Add to all languages** for each one, then these macros will have been applied to BOTH the **GNU C** and **GNU C++** languages. So, click on one and then the other and you should see the macros in both places, like this:
   [image]
2. If you checked the box for **Add to all configurations** for each one, then these macros will have also been applied to all build "Configurations", such as **Debug** and **Release**, as shown here:
   [image]
3. Keep in mind all of the various combinations of "Languages" and "Configuration" are unique. You can set macros for one or both languages for each configuration individually if you don't check the 2 boxes for **Add to all configurations** and **Add to all languages** when adding the macros.
4. If you navigate to *Project Properties* --> **C/C++ Build** --> **Settings** --> **Tool Settings** tab --> **Cross GCC Compiler** --> **Preprocessor** you will also see these macros now defined for all "GCC" C files, when building or indexing!:
   [image]
   Note that you can also edit, add, or delete macros specific to a given "Configuration" or "Language" (this particular place is for the **GNU C** language) right here, rather than as previously done above, if you like. **BUT, the only way to apply a given macro to ALL languages and ALL build configurations at once is doing it how I showed you above.**
5. You can also see these macros are applied to the **GNU C++** build and index settings if you navigate to  *Project Properties* --> **C/C++ Build** --> **Settings** --> **Tool Settings** tab --> **Cross G++ Compiler** --> **Preprocessor**:
   [image]
   Again, to customize macros just for C++ and just for this selected "Configuration" you could edit them right here.

When done adding all macros, click **Apply** or **Apply and Close**. When asked, choose **YES** to re-index the entire project:
[image]

If you didn't click **YES**, you may manually trigger the project to be reindexed by **right-clicking on it in the Project Explorer** and going to --> **Index** --> **Rebuild**.

### Troubleshooting

Update: see also my more-extensive troubleshooting section [on my website here](https://gabrielstaples.com/eclipse-defining-custom-macros-for-indexer/#troubleshooting).

If your settings/macros don't seem to be getting applied, and your code still shows sections blacked-out, indicating the macros for those sections are false or undefined, you may need to do or check the following:

1. Try reindexing your project by **right-clicking on it in the Project Explorer** and going to --> **Index** --> **Rebuild**.
2. You may not have set the macros for the right build configuration or language. You will need to check all of the various build configurations and languages as I showed in the various screenshots above.

   1. Follow the instructions above and re-add the macros, this time BEING SURE TO CHECK THE 2 BOXES FOR **Add to all configurations** and **Add to all languages**.
   2. OR, manually navigate to the *Project Properties* --> **C/C++ Build** --> **Settings** --> **Tool Settings** tab -->

      1. --> **Cross GCC Compiler** --> **Preprocessor** OR
      2. --> **Cross G++ Compiler** --> **Preprocessor**...

   - ...sections to manually configure the macros just for one language and/or configuration, or another. ALL of these settings must be either in-sync or set individually.
3. The easiest place to set these settings, as already stated above, is here: **Right-click on your project** in the "Project Explorer" pane on the left --> **Properties** --> **C/C++ General** --> **Paths and Symbols** --> **Symbols** tab. BUT, if you forgot to check the boxes for **Add to all configurations** and **Add to all languages**, I recommend just deleting the macros and then adding them again, this time checking those boxes.
4. If you don't want to worry about which build Configuration you have selected, and you didn't check the **Add to all configurations** box when you added the macros, you can also change this global workspace setting, but I don't really recommend it:
   **Window** --> **Preferences** --> **C/C++** --> **Indexer** --> select **Use active build configuration**. Again, however, I do NOT use this option myself and do not necessarily recommend you use it either. It's just something to be aware of is all.
   [image]

### See also

1. This answer is also posted on my website here: https://gabrielstaples.com/eclipse-defining-custom-macros-for-indexer/
2. My full Eclipse setup document here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse