# How do I make Eclipse recognize KBUILD_MODNAME?

Tags: linux, eclipse, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I followed [this guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source) to configure Eclipse as IDE for Linux Kernel editing/navigation. It generally works, but Eclipse fails to understand the macro `KBUILD_MODNAME`: I use the macro `pci_register_driver`, which is defined as:

```
#define pci_register_driver(driver)     \
    __pci_register_driver(driver, THIS_MODULE, KBUILD_MODNAME)
```

in `include/linux/pci.h`.

How do I make Eclipse to know this token?

Comment: As far as I understood they provide only possibility yo navigate *existing* stuff. So, it might be you have to build your kernel with newly added modules before indexing like they suggested in the mentioned guide.

Comment: You can define macros for the Eclipse indexer in order to define exactly what `KBUILD_MODNAME` is supposed to be. It will be passed to the Eclipse indexer as a define--essentially like this: `-DKBUILD_MODNAME=whatever_you_want`. See my detailed answer here for instructions how: [How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094447/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

[everything below is based on kernel 4.15.0]

Forming of `KBUILD_MODNAME` can be understood by looking into ‘scripts’ folder of kernel sources:

From Makefile.lib:

```
# These flags are needed for modversions and compiling, so we define them here
# $(modname_flags) defines KBUILD_MODNAME as the name of the module it will
# end up in (or would, if it gets compiled in)
# Note: Files that end up in two or more modules are compiled without the
#       KBUILD_MODNAME definition. The reason is that any made-up name would
#       differ in different configs.
name-fix = $(squote)$(quote)$(subst $(comma),_,$(subst -,_,$1))$(quote)$(squote)
basename_flags = -DKBUILD_BASENAME=$(call name-fix,$(basetarget))
modname_flags  = $(if $(filter 1,$(words $(modname))),\
                 -DKBUILD_MODNAME=$(call name-fix,$(modname)))
```

from Makefile.build:

```
# Default for not multi-part modules
modname = $(basetarget)
$(multi-objs-m)         : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-m:.o=.i)   : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-m:.o=.s)   : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-m:.o=.lst) : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-y)         : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-y:.o=.i)   : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-y:.o=.s)   : modname = $(modname-multi)
$(multi-objs-y:.o=.lst) : modname = $(modname-multi)
```

from Kbuild.include:

```
# filename of target with directory and extension stripped
basetarget = $(basename $(notdir $@))
```

from: Makefile.lib

```
# Finds the multi-part object the current object will be linked into
modname-multi = $(sort $(foreach m,$(multi-used),\
        $(if $(filter $(subst $(obj)/,,$*.o), $($(m:.o=-objs)) $($(m:.o=-y))),$(m:.o=))))
```

With all that, you can basically define `KBUILD_MODNAME` in ‘Objects and Symbols’ to be set to your module name as you define it in your Makefile. Things are a little bit more tricky if you have multiple modules built in a single project...

After solving that you will notice that Eclipse indexer still throws out warnings at you (I assume you are building external module with `MODULE` defined in ‘Objects and Symbols’)

- Problem description: Unused static function '__exittest'
- Problem description: Unused static function '__inittest'
- Problem description: Unused declaration of function 'cleanup_module'
- Problem description: Unused declaration of function  'init_module'

Those are symbols used by kernel module loading/unloading system so Eclipse can know nothing of them. Unfortunately, as of today (Eclipse 4.8.0 with CDT 9.5.2) I cannot configure Code Analysis to exclude those symbols from warnings, so have to suppress warnings putting following to the lines of code where you define module initialization:

```
// @suppress("Unused static function") @suppress("Unused function declaration")
```