# macro passed from compile cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, macros, predefined-macro

I am trying to pass a defined macro to my program at compile time like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // KEY_CNT is not defined in program but passed at compile time
    printf("KEY_CNT: %d", KEY_CNT); 
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with `g++ -DKEY_CNT=2 -O2 test_3.cpp -o test_3` and it works as expected, but the problem is Eclipse cannot resolve 'KEY_CNT'. This is just a toy example, in my original program, many false errors like this with red lines are really annoying.

I think Eclipse might need to be notified of my compile option so that it knows 'KEY_CNT' is defined, so I add `-DKEY_CNT=2` in `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous`, but it still doesn't work.

Any advice to solve this?

======== added ========

Eclipse version: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: As long as it compiles, what exactly is the problem that you have with Eclipse failing to get to know that macros is defined in the compile options?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think maybe my configuration introduced above is not the correct way or not sufficient for Eclipse to know the defination? I'm not sure. Any possbile clue?

Comment: "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)" Unless constrained by other things, I'd suggest you to upgrade to Mars.2 (4.5.2) - Indexer has fewer troubles (at least that's my personal experience)

Comment: I tried Mars but not sure if it was 4.5.2, but suffered many times that it suddenly stopped working and caused computer crash, but when I changed into Luna, everything worked fine. Maybe I should give it a try again to see if the latest version works. Thanks for your information.

Comment: See also: [How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215640/how-can-i-convince-eclipse-cdt-that-a-macro-is-defined-for-source-code-editing-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous

Wrong place.

Should be "C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Preprocessor"

Just verified it works.