# Eclipse - how to define macros (not merely symbols) to resolve to empty

Tags: c++, eclipse, macros, eclipse-cdt

Qt-specific macros break my Eclipse C++ indexing.

In my Qt classes, I'll have something like:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ isEnabled WRITE setEnabled)
```

For the purpose of indexing, I'd like for `Q_PROPERTY()` to resolve to empty statement meaning I want

```
#define Q_PROPERTY() /* blank */
```

I know how to make macros resolve to simple values using Eclipse:

> C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols

**QUESTION**

Within Eclipse, i.e. without creating a separate header that I include solely for indexing, is it possible to define macros to resolve to something else (in my case "empty")?

Comment: I've also added a detailed answer on how to do this here: [How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094447/4561887).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define both object-style and function-style macros in `C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols`.

For example, to define your desired

```
#define Q_PROPERTY() /* blank */
```

macro, in the "Add symbol" dialog, enter `Q_PROPERTY()` under "Name", and `/* blank */` under "Value".

Note that, if your intention is to have CDT ignore Qt `Q_PROPERTY` declarations, you actually want `Q_PROPERTY(...)` as the name, since the macro takes arguments (`Q_PROPERTY()` would only match macro calls with no arguments).