# Eclipse CDT: Where should I define a macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, eclipse-cdt, preprocessor

Where should I define preprocessors macros so that eclipse calls gcc with the `-D marco=def` arguments

I tried with *Project Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include, Path, Macros etc...* but the arguments are not passed to the toolchain.

Comment: See also: [How can I convince Eclipse CDT that a macro is defined for source code editing and code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215640/how-can-i-convince-eclipse-cdt-that-a-macro-is-defined-for-source-code-editing-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is indeed located in Project Properties, but in C/C++ Build:

[image: indeed]